# Mongodb export to csv - mongoexport is failing to export - Help Required

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, export-to-excel, mongoexport

> show dbs

TestDB  0.078GB

> use TestDB

switched to db TestDB

> show collections

Employee

MyCollection

> db.MyCollection.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55cb93c412a2139d0a6078a1"), "MyNames" : "Sanal" }

> mongoexport --db TestDB --collection MyCollection --type=csv --fields MyNames --out D:\contacts.csv

2015-08-22T00:44:20.380+0530 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that error message it looks like you are still in the mongo shell. `mongoexport` is a separate utility. You need to exit the mongo shell, the command is just `exit`. Then enter your mongoexport command again on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for helping, It worked!!!
Will this work only for localhost? if the mongodb is in seperate server how will i export?

Comment: To connect to another server you can append another option `--host`. You can try this out on localhost with `--host localhost:27017`.  See more info in [mongoexport documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport)